# Changing language twice gives error: Requested store is not found

Tags: magento2

> In Magento 2.2 Multiple store views on one store
>
> If you change the language twice in a store this system won't redirect
>   you back to the right store. Instead, it gives a server error with the
>   message: Requested
>
> store is not found
>
> Steps to reproduce
>
> Setup 1 store with two store views
>
> Go to the website
>
> Change the language
>
> Change the language again.
>
> The error will display now

**Expected Result**

> Just change back to the previous store view Actual result Server
>   error: Requested store is not found
>
> Gif showing the problem: https://cl.ly/3c2h2C0E3v1Q

Comment: Please try this :-https://stackoverflow.com/a/39290253/4373980

Comment: Can you tell me what file ? thank you!! @UmeshKumar